# Why does composer remove a folder it doesn't manage

Tags: composer

I have the gesso theme installed in themes/contrib, and since I have not subthemed, all my components and templates live in within its folders. For that reason, I do not manage it with composer.

I needed to install a contrib module, and when I ran composer require, the first thing it did was remove gesso.

Why would this happen, and is there a way to tell it "hands off" ?

Comment: Contrib  folders are managed by composer, they are listed as `installer-path`. In this case it is composer telling you "hands off", use the custom folders (e.g. `themes/custom/...`) instead.

Comment: Makes sense, other than the pedantic fact that composer is contrib and not custom.

Comment: That's exactly why you must never hack core or contrib. Create a subtheme inside themes/custom and add your templates to it. The themes/contrib and modules/contrib folders are normally also ignored from Git, like the vendor/ folder. Never touch. I hope you have some backup of your customizations.

Comment: While I agree that composer makes this impractical, historically, customizing a contrib theme rather than subtheming was not akin to hacking, in that none of the underlying code was necessarily changed. In fact, some themes made subtheming impractical if not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't Composer, per se, that's removing your hacked gesso theme. Drupal uses the [`composer/installers` Composer plugin](https://github.com/composer/installers) to move different Drupal components (e.g. modules, themes, profiles) to the dir where Drupal needs them.

Once Composer has retrieved the `drupal/gesso` package, `composer/installers` will place it the contrib [theme path in `extra.installer-paths`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/b58a924af73e74a7ebf9fcc789f97925baf73fb1/composer.json#L51), thus overwriting your pre-existing hacked theme.

If you don't want Composer & the installers plugin replacing your hacked gesso theme, you could do a couple of things:

- Remove `drupal/gesso` from Composer management so it never tries to update or manage the theme again and add the hacked theme back to its previous location.
- Use the `cweagans/composer-patches` Composer plugin to [patch](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/composer-patches-dependency-your-project-needs/) the `drupal/gesso` theme with your component/template hacks so they're added with every update.

Comment: That was (or I had intended it to be) my original point. Gesso is not in composer json or lock, yet the first thing composer did when being asked to install a contrib module was to remove gesso.

Comment: I do not believe that option one works. Composer always wants full control over all its folders, no matter if `vendor/*` or `contrib/*` from installer plugin. When something in a composer folder exists, that is not in json, then composer is going to remove it. If you manually delete a package line from json, composer will not just leave that package alone, it will delete that package folder on the next run. This happened to your theme: something in folder that is not allowed to exist by json/lock --> delete

Comment: Hmm, I've managed individual modules/themes w/o Composer. It looks like the [gesso theme](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/gesso) doesn't have a `composer.json` in its root. I'm guessing the installers plugin is wiping it away because it doesn't have it. Try adding a `composer.json` to hacked theme repo with the `"type": "drupal-theme"` property to see if the plugin recognizes it and doesn't brush it away.